# Android java foreground service

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

foreground service keeps particular activity in background or whole app
, Like am making an app which gets values from sensor.. and fetch location.. so my question is all class will work in background or just the class in which i implement foreground service

Comment: App will be in foreground service but those things will work which you have to apply for foreground service it means those classes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.